# How can I stop my Collatz Sequence code at 1?

Tags: java, while-loop, collatz

I tried implementing the Collatz Sequence using a `while` loop, but I can't stop the sequence at 1. The code continues. I tried using all my possibilities, but I can't come up with a solution.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class cs{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Starting number: ");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = s.nextInt();
        System.out.print(" " + a);
        while(a>1)
        {
            if(a == 1) break; // this is not working though
            if((a % 2 ) == 0) {
            a = a / 2;
            System.out.print("  " + a);
            }

            Thread.sleep(1000);
            if((a % 2) != 0){
                a = (a * 3) + 1;
                System.out.print(" " + a);
            }

            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second `if` condition here should be an `else` of the first one:

> ```
> if((a%2)==0){
>     // ...
> }
>
> // ...
> if((a%2)!=0){
> ```

Like this:

```
    while (a > 1) {
        if ((a % 2) == 0) {
            a /= 2;
            System.out.print("  " + a);
        } else {
            a = (a * 3) + 1;
            System.out.print("  " + a);
        }
    }
```

I also removed the `if (a == 1)` line which was pointless,
as due to the `while (a > 1)` condition,
that `if` would never be `true`.

Lastly, I recommend to pay more attention to indenting your code correctly,
and to add spaces around operators like I did,
otherwise the code is too difficult to read, understand and debug.

Answer (score 1):

The problem must be that `a` never equals 1. Try printing the value of `a` in each loop and see what it actually equals:

```
while(a > 1)
{
    // This line is not required because if a == 1 then the while loop would terminate anyway:
    //  if(a==1) break; //this is not working though

    if((a%2)==0){
        a = a/2;
        System.out.print("  "+a);
    }

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    if((a%2)!=0){
        a = (a*3)+1;;
        System.out.print("  "+a);
    }

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    System.out.println("a = " + a); // This checks what the value of a actually is
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is performing two steps in the Collatz sequence, instead of just one. Even if `a` is `1`, it will then continue into the second `if`, and turn it to `4`, so the loop will never terminate. Instead, you should use an `else` clause, just just perform one step per iteration of the loop:

```
while (a > 1)  {
    if ((a%2) == 0) {
        a = a / 2;
    } else {
        a = (a * 3) + 1;
    }

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.print("  " + a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## This is enough for your case:

```
while (a > 1 && (a % 2) != 0){
    a /= 2;
    System.out.print(" " + a);
}
```

because if you have a look at your while condition, you will see that `a` is bigger than 1 ==> can't be 1 at all, so, there is no need for the first `if` statement.

### So your class will look like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class cs{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Starting number: ");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = s.nextInt();
        System.out.print(" " + a);

        while (a > 1 && (a % 2) != 0){
            a /= 2;
            System.out.print(" " + a);
        }
}
```